# Delphi TGridLayout iOS gallery scroll

Tags: ios, delphi

I have gotten some results trying to use TGridLayout to hold series of TImage object each with a  bitmap loaded. However, I seem unable to scroll the control? I thought about placing it on a scrollbox, but then I would need a way to size the height of TGridLayout

Comment: Deciding the height of the `TGridLayout` is entirely up to you, I don't see a problem. You can drop it into a scrollbox without problems. However, regarding your recent questions, I have a feeling you should rather go with a single image file and render everything you need into it. I fear you'll be running into performance problems when you're adding a lot of images. Recent iOS apps like OneNote also stopped using native controls, it's just a big image that gets updated from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.VertScrollBox0Resize(Sender: TObject);
var s:string; i, x,y:integer;

begin
 i := VertScrollBox0.tag; //imagecounts
 Gridlayout1.Width := VertScrollBox0.Width;
 x := round( Gridlayout1.Width/Gridlayout1.ItemWidth);
 y :=  round  (Gridlayout1.Tag /x ) ;
 Gridlayout1.Height := y *   Gridlayout1.ItemHeight+(2* Gridlayout1.ItemHeight );
end;
```